How to keep the edited text even after the reload in flutter
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isEnable = false;
  TextEditingController _controller =
      TextEditingController(text: "Festive Leave");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 100,
            child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              enabled: _isEnable,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _isEnable = true;
                });
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

the code is running successfully and I get the output but after the reload the value changes to the old self and the editing part didn't get back to normal after the editing.
anyone please help me to make the text get back to the first state after the editing and need to keep the edited value even after the reload

Do you mean text that you type in TextField change back to "Festive Leave" after hot reload?

yes and it didn't change the editing phase either

The hot reload only rebuilds the parts where the code is changed.
for example, try to edit the name of _controller or change its value, the hot reload will only reload that part.
If you edit the IconButton (for example) only the Icon will be changed and nothing else.
So the text should not get back to "Festive Leave" after a hot reload maybe you meant Hot restart, this wich rebuilds the app and restores everything as it was.
If you want the TextField to get back as it was (unenabled) then you can do this:
setState(() {
    _isEnable = !_isEnable;
});

so when you press the IconButton it will toggle the TextField enable.
Hope that helped.
